# Key repeat after input in pynput

Tags: python, keyboard, pynput

I basically need something to take input from and print it or something else, but whatever I press it will repeat after I (close the program, read text input, etc)

[here is an example:](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/103524696/218342653-e519752b-1ab4-4742-a01e-cd7a8b5d23aa.gif)

what I tried:

I used the keyboard module instead of pynput module
I used getch: it worked but not with keys like space,esc,up,down,etc

code:

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Listener

kk=''
is_released=False
def getkey():
    def on_release(k):
        global is_released
        global kk
        kk=str(k)
        is_released=True
        return False

    with Listener(on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()
    print('\b', end='')
    return kk

while True:
    print(getkey())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#pynput.keyboard.Listener

Parameters:

> suppress (bool) – Whether to suppress events. Setting this to True will prevent the input events from being passed to the rest of the system.

Comment: this worked but why can I not press keys when I'm outside of script?